# Uploading assets to digitalOcean bucket using gulp-s3 in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, gulp, digital-ocean

I am using `gulp-s3` library

Created `gulpfile.js` file in root directory

Here the code use to upload the dist folder

```
console.log('gulf');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var s3 = require('gulp-s3');
//will add to the variable now just for testing
var AWS = {
  key: 'ttvtdxxxx',
  secret: 'ttvtd',
  bucket: 'dev-static-ttvtd-ro',
  region: 'fra1',
  endpoint: 'https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com'
};

var options = {
  uploadPath: 'assets',
  headers: {
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=315360000, no-transform, public',
    'x-amz-acl': 'private'
  },
    failOnError: true 
}; // It will upload the 'src' into '/remote-folder'

gulp.task('default', async function() {
  console.log("Hi! I'm Gulp default task root!");
  gulp.src('./dist/**', { 
    read: false

  }).pipe(s3(AWS, options));
  console.log('task completed!');
});
```

The file and code is working when i run the command `gulp`,
So how i can manage this aws setting so that it work with digitalOcean bucket.
The `dist` folder is not uploaded to do bucket and return no any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Digital Ocean docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3-sdk-examples/) there's no `https://` in the endpoint string.

`gulp-s3` uses `aws-sdk` under the hood (quite an old version actually...)

Personally, I haven't had much success with `gulp-s3` but `gulp-s3-upload` worked better for me as it's more feature rich and it seems to be updated more frequently at the moment.

Here's a sample:

```
const s3upload = require('gulp-s3-upload')();

const s3Config = {
    endpoint: 'fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com', // note no https://
    region: 'fra1',
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
};

gulp.task('upload', () => gulp.src('dist/**')
    .pipe(s3upload({
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        ACL: 'private', 
        Metadata: {
            "uploadedVia": "gulp-s3-upload"
        }
    }, s3Config)));
```